# How to deal with expected + irrelevant failures in 'go test all'?

Tags: go

I'm using NPM to manage build/test/version lifecycle of a go package using go 1.11 modules. Prior to publishing, I'd like to check 'everything', included the modules, so I run: `go test all` (which runs tests in all included modules).

The problem is that the standard `os` package in go 1.11.5 (at least) fail on some Mac versions/environments (including mine). That's OK and irrelevant for my purposes, since the failures are in functions I don't use. However, this causes the publish process to fail since `go test` exits with a non-zero status.

Any advice on how to deal with this?

It would be great if there was a way to run all the tests for functions that are in the call tree of my local tests (`go test all -relevant`). Or, if I could name and skip the tests, that would be fine as well.

I'm aware of the `-run` flag, but that doesn't seem to help because I cannot know beforehand what tests to run, and (from what I've seen) the regex used by `-run` doesn't support negative lookaheads so it would be very tedious to construct a regular expression to exclude certain tests.

Failing `os` tests:

```
--- FAIL: TestStatError (0.00s)
    os_test.go:200: symlink no-such-file symlink: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestHardLink (0.00s)
    os_test.go:694: open "hardlinktestto" failed: open hardlinktestto: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestSymlink (0.00s)
    os_test.go:780: Create("symlinktestto") failed: open symlinktestto: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestLongSymlink (0.00s)
    os_test.go:847: symlink "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef", "longsymlinktestfrom" failed: symlink 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef longsymlinktestfrom: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestRename (0.00s)
    os_test.go:868: open "renamefrom" failed: open renamefrom: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestRenameOverwriteDest (0.00s)
    os_test.go:896: write file "renameto" failed: open renameto: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestAppend (0.00s)
    os_test.go:1684: Open: open append.txt: permission denied
--- FAIL: TestSameFile (0.00s)
    os_test.go:1766: Create(a): open a: permission denied
FAIL
FAIL    os  19.145s
```

Comment: What is the "standard third-party `os` package"? Do you mean the `os` package from the the std library?

Comment: Yes; I clarified.

Comment: Normally one doesn't test imports of a module, as they should be tested in isolation; and testing the stdlib outside of building the go toolchain is even more unusual. If testing `all` is something you really want to do, I would at least wrap the command in a script to filter out the stdlib packages (you could of course do it in a bash one-liner if you really want too).

Comment: You could run `go test ./...` from the module's main folder. Doesn't that work for you? If you also want to test dependencies, run `go mod vendor`, and execute `go test ./...` in the `vendor` folder too (created by `go mod`).

Comment: @JimB According to the official golang modules, it's a good idea to run `go test all` before publishing a package "to check for incompatibilities". https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: I see, it's to verify the transitive dependency versions. While I don't completely agree with the choice to keep the stdlib in the `all` wildcard (history here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/26317), you can still pretty easily filter out the deps in the command line using `go list`.

Comment: @JimB Could you expand on how `go list` would help this situation? I'm aware `go list -f '{{ .Deps }}` would list all the package dependencies, and I can see how one could then test the dependencies directly, but the `os` package, which is failing, still shows up in the dependency list, so it's not obvious what this gets me.

Comment: It seems that there's no elegant solution to the probelm and the best answer is really "suspend the `go test all` until the stdlib is fixed.

Comment: There's examples in the linked issue. `all` is basically equivalent to `go  list -f '{{ join .Deps  " "}}'`, so you can filter out the problematic packages, or filter the entire std lib using something like `go list -f "{{if not .Standard}}{{.ImportPath}}{{end}}" $(go  list -f '{{ join .Deps  " "}}')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to choose which tests are run by OS, architecture, or build tag. For those that are for OS-specific functionality, just make the tests OS-specific. There should be no such thing as "expected failures", these are just tests that are being misapplied.

Comment: I don't follow. I'm familiar with using 'build' tags for my own files, but the problem is a failure in the third party `os` package. I've checked the source, and I don't see build tags in the test to key off. I agree there "should" be no such thing as an "expected failure", but since there evidently is such a thing, I'd like to deal with it.

Comment: If you're talking about `os` in the stdlib, that's not 3rd party; 3rd party would be any dependency that's not part of your project nor part of the stdlib. I highly doubt there's a failure in the `os` package - the tests pass before they release a new stable version. Your question didn't indicate what test(s) were failing specifically so it's hard to offer more insight than that.

Comment: I apologize for my previous (deleted) comment. I did say which test was failing. The tests dealing with hardlinks in the `os` package. Sure, I could have been more clear. But the basic question still stands as the standard `os` package test does absolutely fail and rather than debate semantics, I'd like to find a solution. If you have one, I'd very much like to understand it, because as I understand your current answer, it does not seem relevant.

Comment: And, since you brought it up, I used the term 'third party' because I was thinking of how one would solve this in general, where you want to 'go test all' which entails tests from everything, so was using 'third party' as a blanket term for "not mine", which seems entirely appropriate to me. The fact that the failing test is in the standard lib is not relevant to the question.

Comment: It is relevant in some respects, for example, the fact that the stdlib is well-tested on all supported platforms prior to any version being released as stable. The `os` tests do not fail on darwin/amd64: https://build.golang.org/

Comment: Except that they do, in some cases, as shown by the evidence provided above, and confirmed by the golang team: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28387. I appreciate your input, and I agree that the current state of affairs is transitory and that the best solution is perhaps to wait till the tests are fixed, but you keep insisting on things which are not in fact true. Anyone can make mistakes, and I'm asking how to work around those mistakes when they inevitably crop up.